# Chromium (snap) Headless print-to-pdf says file written but no file found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, chromium

I'm updating my old Chromium (90 via apt-get) on Ubuntu 16.04 to the latest release (109 via snap). I'm using it to generate PDFs files but since the update, my commands are not working as expected. Here's one of them with the result :

```
chromium --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="/tmp/TEST.pdf" https://www.google.com --no-sandbox
```

The result :

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.avail/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf", line 10: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
[0116/164015.731713:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0116/164015.790134:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(393)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[0116/164016.266441:INFO:headless_shell.cc(107)] 109751 bytes written to file /tmp/TEST.pdf
```

But TEST.pdf is actually no more created anywhere. It used to work with the previous version. The only difference I see is the first Fontconfig warning. If I open this file to delete one of the value in test, the warning disappears but the pdf file still isn't created.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is due to the snap not being able to write to /tmp.

The command fails if I run it as is on my machine but succeeds if I change the output file to

> --print-to-pdf="~/TEST.pdf"

Comment: That's not working either :/ When I do this, I have an error : `Failed to write file ~/TEST.pdf: No such file or directory (2)` . And of course but that's normal, if I want to export to "/TEST.pdf", I have a readonly filesystem error. What's strange is that my attempt in /tmp outputs that bytes have written to file...

Comment: Try it with the full path ie `/home/XXX` instead of `~`.

Comment: Thank you very much Neal, that's working fine in my home/USER folder. So strange it would say it's writing to tmp if it cannot. I'll try to give permission in tmp to the snap! Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, I got what happened and I put it here in case it could be useful for someone else. Snaps seem to have their own tmp folder. So when I wanted to save the file to `/tmp/TEST.pdf` it actually saved it in `/tmp/snap-private-tmp/snap.chromium/tmp` ! I figured that out when reading about snaps having a per-app tmp folder [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/accessing-tmp-from-snaps/22384)